# Is it possible to use DictVectorizer on chunked data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import chunked data using python pandas csv reader,to overcome memory error, and use DicVectorizer to transform string to float dtypes. But I could see two different strings are having same codes after transformation. Do we have alternative/option to do the data type transformation on chunked data?

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas 0.19, you can declare columns as Categorial in read_csv. See [documentaion](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190-enhancements-read-csv-categorical).

So as an example for the doc, you can type a column named `col1` in your csv like this and reduce memory footprint:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype={'col1': 'category'})
```

Comment: In this case, is it okay if two different strings of two different columns have same code?

Comment: By construction of categorials, two different strings have two different codes. In any case the goal of categorials is that you manipulate your data as strings and codes are hidden and used behind the scene for performance. You shouldn't worry about this